# Can we remove the repeating string elements here? Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

[image]

```
 static IEnumerable<MaxDiscountOwner> Task(IEnumerable<Supplier> supplierList,
            IEnumerable<SupplierDiscount> supplierDiscountList)
        {

            var b = supplierDiscountList.OrderBy(x => x.ShopName).ThenBy(a => a.Discount).
            Select(x => new MaxDiscountOwner
            {
                ShopName = x.ShopName,
                Discount = x.Discount,
                Owner = supplierList.Where(a => a.Id == x.SupplierId).FirstOrDefault()
            }).OrderByDescending(g => g.Discount);

            return b;
            
        }
```

I want to remove the repeated `MaxDiscountOwner` elements after `OrderByDescending(g => g.Discount)` by string `shop`, how can I do it and can I do it at all?

`supplierDiscountList` is array `new SupplierDiscount { Discount = 5.0, ShopName = "shop1", SupplierId = 1 },` similar objects.

```
MaxDiscountOwner[] expected = new[]
new MaxDiscountOwner
                    {
                        Discount = 5.0, ShopName = "shop1",
                        Owner = new Supplier{Adress = "adress 1", Id = 1, YearOfBirth = 2000}
                    },
 new MaxDiscountOwner
                    {
                        Discount = 34.0, ShopName = "shop2",
                        Owner = new Supplier{Adress = "adress 2", Id = 2, YearOfBirth = 1961}
                    },
and until we run out of stores
```

supplierList its array of "Supplier{Adress = "adress 1", Id = 1, YearOfBirth = 2000}, .."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I got it right

```
 static IEnumerable<MaxDiscountOwner> Task(IEnumerable<Supplier> supplierList,
        IEnumerable<SupplierDiscount> supplierDiscountList)
    {

        return  supplierDiscountList.OrderBy(x => x.ShopName).ThenBy(a => a.Discount)
                                    .Select(x => new MaxDiscountOwner
                                    {
                                        ShopName = x.ShopName,
                                        Discount = x.Discount,
                                        Owner = supplierList.Where(a => a.Id == x.SupplierId).FirstOrDefault()
                                    })
                                    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Discount)
                                    .GroupBy(x => (x.ShopName ?? "").Trim()).OrderBy(x=>x.Key) // maybe add ToLower() yet
                                    .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(g => g.Discount).First());           

        
    }
```